# Finding collocation patterns in Java

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working in a project which require the use of collocations. I have created the following code to extract them. The code takes a string and returns a list of the collocation patterns in this string. I have used Stanford POS to do the tagging.

I need your suggestion on the code, it seems very slow as I process huge amount of text.
Any suggestion to improve the code would be highly appreciated.

```
/**
*
*  A COLLOCATION is an expression consisting of two or more words that
*  correspond to some conventional way of saying things.
* 
*  I used the seventh Part-of-speech-tag patterns for collocation filtering that 
*  were suggested by Justeson and Katz(1995).
*  These patterns are:
* 
*  -----------------------------------------
*  |Tag |     Pattern Example              |
*  -----------------------------------------
*  |AN  | linear function                  |
*  |NN  | regression coefficients          |
*  |AAN | Gaussian random variable         |
*  |ANN | cumulative distribution function |
*  |NAN | mean squared error               |
*  |NNN | class probability function       |
*  |NPN | degrees of freedom               |                     
*  -----------------------------------------
*  Where A=adjective, P=preposition, & N=noun.
* 
*  Stanford POS have been used for the extraction process. 
*  see: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#Download
* 
*  more on collocation:    http://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf
*  more on POS:            http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J93/J93-2004.pdf
*  
*/

public class GetCollocations {
    public static ArrayList<String> GetCollocations(String text) throws IOException,                ClassNotFoundException{
       MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/wsj-0-18-left3words.tagger");
       String[] tagged = tagger.tagString(text).split("\\s+");

       ArrayList<String> collocations = new ArrayList();
       for (int i = 0; i < tagged.length; i++) {

           String pot = tagged[i].substring(tagged[i].indexOf("_") + 1);
           if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") ||    pot.equals("NNPS")) {

               pot = tagged[i + 1].substring(tagged[i + 1].indexOf("_") + 1);
               if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {

                collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]));

                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);
                if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            } else if (pot.equals("JJ") || pot.equals("JJR") || pot.equals("JJS")) {
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);

                if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            } else if (pot.equals("IN")) {
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);

                if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            }


        } else if (pot.equals("JJ") || pot.equals("JJR") || pot.equals("JJS")) {
            pot = tagged[i + 1].substring(tagged[i + 1].indexOf("_") + 1);
            if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]));
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);
                if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            } else if (pot.equals("JJ") || pot.equals("JJR") || pot.equals("JJS")) {
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);
                if (pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return collocations;

}
public static String GetWordWithoutTag(String wordWithTag){
    String wordWithoutTag = wordWithTag.substring(0,wordWithTag.indexOf("_"));
    return wordWithoutTag;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are processing anywhere near 15,000 words per second then you are maxing out with the POS tagger.  According to the Stanford [Stanford POS tagger FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#h):

```
on a 2008 nothing-special Intel server, it tags about 15000 words per second
```

The rest of your algorithm appears fine, though if you really want to squeeze some juice out of it you could pre-allocate an Array as a static class variable instead of the ArrayList.  Essentially sacrificing the upfront memory costs to not have to instantiate the ArrayList with each call or suffer the [amortized O(n) cost](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of adding elements.

Also just a suggestion on improving the readability of the code, you may consider using some private methods for checking what part of speech the `pot` variable is,

```
private static Boolean  _isNoun(String pot) {
    if(pot.equals("NN") || pot.equals("NNS") || pot.equals("NNP") || pot.equals("NNPS")) return true;
    else return false;
}

private static Boolean _isAdjective(String pot){
    if(pot.equals("JJ") || pot.equals("JJR") || pot.equals("JJS")) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Also if I'm not mistaking you should be able to simplify what you are doing, combining some of the `if` statements.  This won't really speed up your code but it will make it nicer to work with.  Please go through this carefully, I have just tried to simplify your logic to demonstrate my point.  Keep in mind the code below is UNTESTED:

```
public static ArrayList<String> GetCollocations(String text) throws IOException,                ClassNotFoundException{
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/wsj-0-18-left3words.tagger");
    String[] tagged = tagger.tagString(text).split("\\s+");
    ArrayList<String> collocations = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < tagged.length; i++) {
        String pot = tagged[i].substring(tagged[i].indexOf("_") + 1);

        if (_isNoun(pot) || _isAdjective(pot)) {
            pot = tagged[i + 1].substring(tagged[i + 1].indexOf("_") + 1);

            if (_isNoun(pot) || _isAdjective(pot)) {
                collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]));
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);

                if (_isNoun(pot)) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            } else if (pot.equals("IN")) {
                pot = tagged[i + 2].substring(tagged[i + 2].indexOf("_") + 1);

                if (_isNoun(pot)) {
                    collocations.add(GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 1]) + " " + GetWordWithoutTag(tagged[i + 2]));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return collocations;

}
```